# Can I have webpack remove script and style elements from template and add them to their respective bundles?

Tags: webpack

With a legacy framework we get an output where we have many script (in-file, without `src`) and style elements scattered throughout the html. Can we treat the generated HTML file as the template in webpack and have webpack (perhaps using a plugin) remove all styles and add them to our bundle.css and do the same for all the script tags?